# Virtual Server vs Dedicated Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, virtual-machines

Could experts help me summarily tell me before deploying my web service App? Please. What is the downside of choosing Virtual Server over Dedicated Server?

Answer (score 1):

A dedicated server is its own machine. A virtual server is a virtual machine on a computer with other virtual servers. virtual servers need to compete for cpu time if theres more virtual machines than cpu cores. If another vm somehow manages to crash the host (operating system running the virtual machines) then it will affect the other virtual machines, but this would almost never happen on amazon servers.

If your web service app will need a lot of cpu time, and needs to be run immediately, you might want to ask amazon if the vm's have their own dedicated cores, and about performance in general. other than that, the performance difference between the two wont be noticeable at all. I suggest the virtual server as it would be cheaper.